# Failed to start Kubernetes API Server

Tags: centos, kubernetes

This is a cloud based CentOS 7 I have open ports 8080, 80, 22 in cloud FW but not sure why this doesn';t work .

/etc/etcd/etcd.conf file

```
    # [member]
    ETCD_NAME=default
    ETCD_DATA_DIR="/var/lib/etcd/default.etcd"
    #ETCD_WAL_DIR=""
    #ETCD_SNAPSHOT_COUNT="10000"
    #ETCD_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL="100"
    #ETCD_ELECTION_TIMEOUT="1000"
    #ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS="http://localhost:2380"
    ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS="http://localhost:2379"
    #ETCD_MAX_SNAPSHOTS="5"
    #ETCD_MAX_WALS="5"
    #ETCD_CORS=""
    #
    #[cluster]
    #ETCD_INITIAL_ADVERTISE_PEER_URLS="http://localhost:2380"
    # if you use different ETCD_NAME (e.g. test), set ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER value for this name, i.e. "test=http://..."
    #ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER="default=http://localhost:2380"
    #ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE="new"
    #ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_TOKEN="etcd-cluster"
    ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS="http://localhost:2379"
    #ETCD_DISCOVERY=""
    #ETCD_DISCOVERY_SRV=""
    #ETCD_DISCOVERY_FALLBACK="proxy"
    #ETCD_DISCOVERY_PROXY=""
    #
    #[proxy]
    #ETCD_PROXY="off"
    #ETCD_PROXY_FAILURE_WAIT="5000"
    #ETCD_PROXY_REFRESH_INTERVAL="30000"
    #ETCD_PROXY_DIAL_TIMEOUT="1000"
    #ETCD_PROXY_WRITE_TIMEOUT="5000"
    #ETCD_PROXY_READ_TIMEOUT="0"
    #
    #[security]
    #ETCD_CERT_FILE=""
    #ETCD_KEY_FILE=""
    #ETCD_CLIENT_CERT_AUTH="false"
    #ETCD_TRUSTED_CA_FILE=""
    #ETCD_PEER_CERT_FILE=""
    #ETCD_PEER_KEY_FILE=""
    #ETCD_PEER_CLIENT_CERT_AUTH="false"
    #ETCD_PEER_TRUSTED_CA_FILE=""
    #
    #[logging]
    #ETCD_DEBUG="false"
    # examples for -log-package-levels etcdserver=WARNING,security=DEBUG
    #ETCD_LOG_PACKAGE_LEVELS=""

/etc/kubernetes/apiserver

    # kubernetes system config
    #
    # The following values are used to configure the kube-apiserver
    #

    # The address on the local server to listen to.
    KUBE_API_ADDRESS="--address= 0.0.0.0"

    # The port on the local server to listen on.
    KUBE_API_PORT="--port=8080"

    # Port minions listen on
    KUBELET_PORT="--kubelet-port=10250"

    # Comma separated list of nodes in the etcd cluster
    KUBE_ETCD_SERVERS="--etcd_servers=http://127.0.0.1:2379"

    # Address range to use for services
    KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES="--service-cluster-ip-range=10.254.0.0/16"

    # default admission control policies
    KUBE_ADMISSION_CONTROL="--admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,NamespaceExists,LimitRanger,SecurityContextDeny,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota"

    # Add your own!
    KUBE_API_ARGS=""
```

and then I used journalctl -xn

journalctl -xn

```
-- Logs begin at Fri 2017-03-10 11:15:11 UTC, end at Fri 2017-03-10 13:42:17 UTC. --
Mar 10 13:42:17 localhost.localdomain kube-controller-manager[39099]: E0310 13:42:17.377324   39099 leaderelection.go:228] error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-controller-manager: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-controller-manager: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
Mar 10 13:42:17 localhost.localdomain kube-scheduler[39132]: E0310 13:42:17.495553   39132 leaderelection.go:228] error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-scheduler: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-scheduler: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
Mar 10 13:42:17 localhost.localdomain kube-scheduler[39132]: E0310 13:42:17.980339   39132 reflector.go:199] k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/scheduler/factory/factory.go:466: Failed to list *api.PersistentVolume: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/persistentvolumes?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
Mar 10 13:42:17 localhost.localdomain kube-scheduler[39132]: E0310 13:42:17.980435   39132 reflector.go:199] k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/scheduler/factory/factory.go:481: Failed to list *extensions.ReplicaSet: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/apis/extensions/v1beta1/replicasets?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
Mar 10 13:42:17 localhost.localdomain kube-scheduler[39132]: E0310 13:42:17.981756   39132 reflector.go:199] pkg/controller/informers/factory.go:89: Failed to list *api.PersistentVolumeClaim: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/persistentvolumeclaims?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
Mar 10 13:42:17 localhost.localdomain kube-scheduler[39132]: E0310 13:42:17.983770   39132 reflector.go:199] k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/scheduler/factory/factory.go:460: Failed to list *api.Pod: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%21%3D%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DFailed%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DSucceeded&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
Mar 10 13:42:17 localhost.localdomain kube-scheduler[39132]: E0310 13:42:17.983834   39132 reflector.go:199] k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/scheduler/factory/factory.go:473: Failed to list *api.ReplicationController: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/replicationcontrollers?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
Mar 10 13:42:17 localhost.localdomain kube-scheduler[39132]: E0310 13:42:17.983897   39132 reflector.go:199] k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/scheduler/factory/factory.go:470: Failed to list *api.Service: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
Mar 10 13:42:17 localhost.localdomain kube-scheduler[39132]: E0310 13:42:17.984741   39132 reflector.go:199] k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/scheduler/factory/factory.go:463: Failed to list *api.Node: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/nodes?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
Mar 10 13:42:17 localhost.localdomain kube-scheduler[39132]: E0310 13:42:17.984782   39132 reflector.go:199] k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/scheduler/factory/factory.go:457: Failed to list *api.Pod: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3D%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DFailed%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DSucceeded&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
```

It seems that it refuses the connection

Comment: which version of kubernetes do you use?

Answer (score 0):

The connection refused you're getting isn't from the etcd connection. The controller manager is trying to connect to the kubernetes API.

Start an instance of the API (which is the component that connects to etcd) and it should work.